# Sobel operator for gradient angle

Tags: opencv

I want to find the direction of the stroke in text. How can the Sobel operator be used for this purpose?

[image]

This image shows `dp`, which is the gradient direction. I wanted to know how I can apply the Sobel operator to find which pixel to choose, from `p` to `q`, along the path `sp`, to find the end pixel `q` on the edge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find x derivative of image, then y derivative.

```
Sobel(Img,gxx,CV_32FC1,1,0); //  x derivative
Sobel(Img,gyy,CV_32FC1,0,1); //  y derivative
```

After that find phase 
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#phase

```
phase(gxx,gyy,angles,inDegrees);
```

Comment: I don't think I found a built-in for finding magnitudes as well. Is there one?

Comment: Yes, take a look at cv::magnitude.  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#magnitude