# stroke width transform opencv using python

Tags: opencv

I have an image I wanted to find stroke width in the image. So far i am able to find phase angle from Sobel operator.Now how to use it find width.

[Sobel operator for gradient angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381704/sobel-operator-for-gradient-angle)

give post related to finding angle but not the stroke width please help.

Comment: Another project in Python of the SWT implementation can be found here : https://github.com/ag-ds-bubble/swtloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have initial point and angle(gradient).

Then using equation

```
   x2 = x1 + length * cos(θ) 
   y2 = y1 + length * sin(θ)
```

and θ should be in radians

```
   θ= angle * 3.14 / 180.0
```

In a loop find x2,y2 by increasing length gradually, and for each x2,y2 access pixel value and check whether it is your stroke color, if it is increment a counter else break the loop and take the value of counter as your stroke width.

```
      Vec3b pix=image.at<Vec3b>(y2,x2);
      if(pix==yourstrokColor)
           strokeWidth++;
      else break;
```

Comment: I tested this as code which work well.But I am not able to understand how equation at first work.It would be helpful if you can explain some math about.thank for solution...

Comment: Acually it is parametric equation of circle you can find nore info [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html)